# Como verificar mais de um nivel de um objeto sem que o código fique visualmente feio?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lógica

Tenho um objeto **postCardImage** ele é preenchido por um retorno que eu tenho na minha API, o problema é que preciso testar todo o objeto que retornou para entao atribui-lo.

Faço o teste assim:

```
postCardImage:
  post._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"] |
  post._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0] |
  post._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].media_details |
  post._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].media_details.sizes |
  post._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].media_details.sizes.full |
  post._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].media_details.sizes.full.source_url ? post._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].media_details.sizes.full.source_url : ""
```

porem achei isso muito grande e feio, queria saber se nao teria um forma mais elegante de testar isso?

**por exemplo:**

```
 if(post._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].media_details.sizes.full.source_url){
  console.log("objeto ok");
 }
```

Isso é um problema muito comum no meu dia a dia, porem ainda nao tive uma solução.
O que é preciso fazer para melhorar essa pergunta?

Comment: Porque os negativos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função para isso:

```
function get(obj, path) {
    const attributes = path.split('.');

    for (let attribute of attributes) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(attribute)) {
            return null;
        }

        obj = obj[attribute];
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Ela basicamente percorre o caminho de atributos que você deseja e se algum deles não existir retorna `null`. Pontos fracos desta solução é que se o valor desejado for `null` você não conseguirá distinguir se retornou o valor corretamente ou se retornou `null` porque não encontrou o atributo; outro é que como é utilizado o caractere ponto como separador, nenhum dos atributos pode possuí-lo no nome (isso pode ser contornado alterando o separador para outro caractere).

```js
function get(obj, path) {
    const attributes = path.split('.');

    for (let attribute of attributes) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(attribute)) {
            return null;
        }

        obj = obj[attribute];
    }

    return obj;
}

const obj = {
    _embedded: {
        "wp:featuredmedia": [
            {
                media_details: {
                    sizes: {
                        full: {
                            source_url: 'Conteudo'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

const existe = get(obj, '_embedded.wp:featuredmedia.0.media_details.sizes.full.source_url');
const naoExiste = get(obj, '_embedded.wp:featuredmedia.1.media_details.sizes.full.source_url');

console.log(existe, naoExiste);
```

Comment: Boa resposta. Outras ideias que me ocorreram foi o `?.` que está em Stage 1 nas sugestões do TC39. E outra seria ter um `try/catch` mas que não faz o código mais bonito e pode esconder outros erros... `+1`